# why doesn't flutter update the status of my widgets?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, setstate, flutter-widget

I am using the shared_preferences within my app to save some data
but they only update the second time I open them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prefs.setInt` is Future method, try putting `await` before all of it.

```dart
async{
   final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance ();
   
    ///others 
   await  prefs.setInt ('s$current month $current year', s);
   setState (() {  });
  }
```

And create another method to fetch data on initState like

```dart
  fetchData()async{
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance ();
    hours  = prefs.getInt(...);
   ///.... 
    setState(() {  });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
     super.initState();
     fetchData();
  }
```